# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput minFreeDiskSpaceLimit not working

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am trying to prevent AVCaptureSession from adding an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput when there is not enough disk space left. I'm using the following code inside viewDidload for testing:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 100 // 100 MB
movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(45, Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC)) // 45 sec

if (session.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput)) {
    print("Output added")
    session.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
} else {
    print("Not enough disk space??")
}
```

But somehow the function 'canAddOutput' always returns true. I'm testing it on a real device and only have 69.4 MB space left. Why is it not returning false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `AVCaptureOutput` header file, on `minFreeDiskSpaceLimit`:

> Specifies the minimum amount of free space, in bytes, required for recording to continue on a given volume.

The error is reported via the `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:` delegate method.

So the fact that `minFreeDiskSpaceLimit` defines a condition for *continued* recording and the error is reported via a finish delegate method suggests to me that you must first start the capture session to use it.